# CopyPipe of DriverKit IOUSBHostInterface fails with kIOReturnError (0xe00002bc)

Tags: macos, macos-catalina, driverkit, macos-system-extension

For my own edification, I'm trying to read some audio data from a USB audio interface using a DriverKit System Extension.

My `IOProviderClass` is `IOUSBHostInterface`. I can successfully `Open()` the interface, but `CopyPipe()` returns `kIOReturnError` (`0xe00002bc`). Why can't I copy the pipe?

To be able to open the interface at all, I had to outmatch `AppleUSBAudio` so my `IOKitPersonalities` explicitly match the `bConfigurationValue`, `bInterfaceNumber`, `idVendor`, `idProduct`, and `bcdDevice` keys. This list may not be minimal.

In `ioreg` I can normally see the interfaces (sometimes only my matching one is there, although I think this is a degenerate situation). I see a `AppleUserUSBHostHIDDevice` child on some of my other interfaces. Could this be the problem? Normally the device has no problem being both USBAudio and HID. I am trying unsuccessfully to out match HID too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was passing the wrong endpoint address to `CopyPipe()`.

To find an endpoint address you need to enumerate through the `IOUSBDescriptorHeader`s in the `IOUSBConfigurationDescriptor` and examine the descriptors with `bDescriptorType` equal to `kIOUSBDescriptorTypeEndpoint`.

`IOUSBGetNextDescriptor()` from `USBDriverKit/AppleUSBDescriptorParsing.h` is made for this and will save you from having think about pointer manipulation.

If the endpoint is in a different alternate setting, then you need to switch the interface to that one with `SelectAlternateSetting()`.

```
void
enumerate_configs(const IOUSBConfigurationDescriptor *configDesc) {
    const IOUSBDescriptorHeader *curHeader = NULL;
    
    while ((curHeader = IOUSBGetNextDescriptor(configDesc, curHeader))) {
        switch (curHeader->bDescriptorType) {
            case kIOUSBDescriptorTypeEndpoint: {
                auto endpoint = (const IOUSBEndpointDescriptor *)curHeader;
                os_log(OS_LOG_DEFAULT, "Endpoint bLength: %{public}i, bDescriptorType: %i, bEndpointAddress: %i, bmAttributes: 0x%x, wMaxPacketSize: %i, bInterval: %i",
                       endpoint->bLength,
                       endpoint->bDescriptorType,
                       endpoint->bEndpointAddress,  // pass this to CopyPipe()
                       endpoint->bmAttributes,
                       endpoint->wMaxPacketSize,
                       endpoint->bInterval);
            }
                break;
            default:
                os_log(OS_LOG_DEFAULT, "some other type: %{public}i", curHeader->bDescriptorType);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```